# Batch script to find an empty file in a folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a requirement to identify a zero KB file in a folder and write the output to a text file. Below is the code I found by using batch script and I would like to customize the same as per my below requirement.

```
@echo off
set out=found.txt
(for /r c:\myfolderfilestosearch %%F in (*.txt) do (if %%~zF LSS 1 echo %%F)) > %out%
pause
```

I would actually want to **create & write** the result to file **if and only if** the above folder has any of the 0kb files only, but my above script creates a txt file for every instance even if there are no 0KB files.

I think we can implement it by using **if else** but as I said I am new and appreciate if someone guides on it with a script.

P.S. I am fine to have a script written in powershell as well.Thanks.

Comment: @Joey Thanks for editing the post Joey!

Comment: `for %%a in (%out%) do if %%~za == 0 del %out%` (I would use `== 0` or `equ 0` instead of `lss 1`)

Comment: You want to write the result only if the folder has some files with 0kb size, or if the folder only has 0kb files and no other files? What's with the "batch script, new to batch script, here's my batch script" - *tag [powershell]*?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Hello, yes I want to write the output to a file only when any of the files in the folder contains 0kb size and the folder can have "n" number of files with various sizes, but I am interested to write the file if any of the files are of 0kb size. To be more precise, I am looking for this solution either from batch script or powershell script anything will suffice. Hope I answered.

Comment: What exactly is "the result"? is it the path/name of the first empty file in the each directory, or should it be the respective directory path/name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\myfolderfilestsearch -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Length -eq 0 } | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Add-Content -Path found.txt
```

To recreate the output file for each run:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\myfolderfilestsearch -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Length -eq 0 } | Select -ExpandProperty FullName) | Set-Content -Path found.txt
```

Comment: The above is useful and working fine, but when I rerun the powershell script I can see data being duplicated. Instead, is it possible to recreate the file everytime when I rerun the powershell script?

Comment: updated with an example. parentheses are added so that all data generated by the set of commands within them is passed to `Set-Content` only once. Replaced `Add-Content` with `Set-Content`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: the redirection doesn't care, if you are actually writing data. It is creating the file anyways. But you can get rid of it afterwards, if it's size is zero (no data written)

```
@echo off
set out=found.txt
(for /r c:\myfolderfilestosearch %%F in (*.*) do if %%~zF LSS 1 echo %%F) > %out%
for %%a in (%out%) do if %%~za == 0 del %out% 
pause
```

(I would prefer `== 0` or `equ 0` instead of `lss`)

Answer (score 0):

You have too many unnecessary parens, and you don't need `/r`. This works on my machine:

```
@echo off
set out=found.txt
for %%F in (c:\myfolderfilestosearch\*.*) do if %%~zF LSS 1 echo %%F >> %out%
pause
```

Note that if you don't specify a specific folder location for *found.txt*, it will be in whatever folder the batch file itself is located. If you don't want that, either specify a path for that file or change into that folder using `cd` in the batch file:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\myfolderfilestosearch"
set out=found.txt
for %%F in (*.*) do if %%~zF LSS 1 echo %%F >> %out%
pause
```

or

```
@echo off
set out="C:\myfolderfilestosearch\found.txt"
for %%F in (c:\myfolderfilestosearch\*.*) do if %%~zF LSS 1 echo %%F >> %out%
pause
```

Edit: Use `>>` to append to the output file.

Comment: actually the parantheses arount the complete `for` loop are neccessary to not overwrite the outfile with every finding.

Comment: @Ken White Thanks for writing the above, but actually I am looking for a script where I want to write the result to found.txt file if and only if the above folder has any of the 0kb files only. As per your above script it looks like it writes the file everytime we exeute the batch. Let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Not using `>>`, which appends. I should have mentioned that change directly to make it more apparent. (Thanks to @LotPings for adding it.)

Comment: @MGM: No, it adds only the zero byte file if any is found. If no files that are 0 bytes in size are found, it does not write anything. (I've tested both ways.) If you need to clean up a file created by a previous run, then delete it at the top of the batch file.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, the above is correct but that is creating a file even after there are no 0kb files in the folder. I wish the file found.txt shouldn't be created if there are any 0kb files in the folder and the found.txt file should only be created and written only if there are any 0kb files residing in the folder. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: @MGM: No, it does not. It works exactly as you describe wanting it to work. I've repeatedly tested it with and without a zero byte file in the folder, and it only creates found.txt if there actually *is* a zero byte file. I suspect you're seeing one from a previous run. Delete found.txt, remove any zero byte file from the folder, and run it; found.txt is **not** created using the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting output and delaying the "write to file" part isn't that simple in batch. It's easier to write the output to a file regardless, and delete the file if you encounter a file with non-zero size.

```
@echo off

set "out=found.txt"
set "allzero=y"

(for /r C:\myfolderfilestosearch %%F in (*.*) do (
  if %%~zF gtr 0 (
    set "allzero=n"
    goto :done
  )
  echo %%F
))>"%out%"

:done
if "%allzero%"=="n" del /q "%out%"
```

In PowerShell you might do it like this:

```
$allzero = $true
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\myfolderfilestosearch -File -Recurse -Force |
         ForEach-Object {
           if ($_.Length -gt 0) {
             $allzero = $false
             continue
           }
           $_.FullName
         }

if ($allzero) {
  $files | Set-Content 'found.txt'
}
```