# Batch - If find content in a logfile then write it to another logfile, otherwise do nothing

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a small batch that searches a log file for Errorcodes and when found write it into another one. It creates always a new logfile, but i just want to create a new logfile when content is found.

```
type *.log |find /i "0x00000002" >> C:\Batch\ERRORLOG_%date%.log
type *.log |find /i "0x00000003" >> C:\Batch\ERRORLOG_%date%.log
type *.log |find /i "0x00000005" >> C:\Batch\ERRORLOG_%date%.log
type *.log |find /i "0x00000020" >> C:\Batch\ERRORLOG_%date%.log
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You need to be more specific with your task. What do you want writing to the errorlog file? _Bear in mind that an error log with lines which do not show their originating document seem pointless_. Also are you aware that characters normally found in %DATE% are not allowed in file names? Please edit/update your question after having provided more data to help fulfill your request.

Comment: I want to read the Errors from Backup Log and monitor a folder where Errorlog is located to see if an error occured. If necessary i go to full log. Why are characters in %date% not allowed?

Comment: Not in all possible %DATE% variable outputs, but many use backward or forward slashes, which are disallowed and others use a dot which I personally think is awful in a file name. Additionally many %DATE% formats are not in an easily sortable order. If you take a look at my answer you'll see that I catered for all of these potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `findstr`, which is a bit more flexible (i.e. can handle more than one searchstring):

```
type *.log |findstr /i "0x00000002 0x00000003 0x00000005 0x00000020" >logfile
```

see `findstr/?` for more options

Adapted to your comment *"i just want to create a logfile if content is found"*:

you can [delete the resulting file if it's empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140368/2152082) at the end. If you don't want it to be even created, you have to use a `for` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type *.log 2^>nul ^|findstr /i "0x00000002 0x00000003 0x00000005 0x00000020"') do echo %%a>>logfile
```

The trick here is, that `for` does only execute the code after `do`, if there is a finding (so no redirection happens, if there are no findings). Please note, that this method is much slower because of repetitive `FileOpen` and `FileClose` events (you don't notice it with small files, but with a big number of findings it can take some dozend seconds in comparison to just a few milliseconds)

Comment: That works nice, but i just want to create a logfile if content is found? How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't answer my concerns regarding the %DATE% in the filename. So here's an alternative which takes account of that.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "EOL=L DELIMS=" %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET LOCALDATETIME') DO FOR %%B IN (%%A
    ) DO SET "TD=%%B"
DIR/B/A-D *.LOG^
    |FINDSTR/IRF:/ "0x0000000[235] 0x00000020">C:\BATCH\ERRORLOG_%TD:~,8%.log
```

Comment: in some localizations, `%date%` is perfectly fine for filenames (for example it gives me `22.10.2016` (not nice, but valid)). I'd also prefer language independent solutions like yours.